# Icons On Launcher and Taskbar Different

Tags: unity, login, launcher, icons

A few days ago, this issue started popping up: Whenever I log in to Ubuntu, the icons in the Launcher bar and the Taskbar look kind of strange. Unlike the neat icons Ubuntu came with, these icons are strange and old-y looking, like the icons for the File Explorer and Wifi and Bluetooth. I can change them back by opening a terminal and running`unity`. The login screen is fine, but this only happens after i log in. Could anyone tell me why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot (use https://imgur.com)

Comment: https://imgur.com/MCTX5ta (before i run unity) versus https://imgur.com/KOvbhZw (after i run unity) look at the taskbar

Comment: for some reason, today when i logged in, the launcher icons were normal. also, the menu options (the drop down menu when you click on, say, wifi) are gray, though i can still click on them. Would it help if i told you that right about when this problem started, i was trying to purge and remove xfce and kde plasma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely you have File Manager running on startup which has a different set of icons in Ubuntu. If you open the app **Advanced Settings**, and uncheck '*Have file manager handle the desktop*' disabled this might help.

Comment: File manager? I don't have a program with that name. Nautilus is sort of a file manager, if you mean that, but i can't find any Advanced Settings or anything else you mentioned.